# Retrieving multiple Records,columns using Joins and pluck

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, pluck

I found a weird behaviour from Active Record Pluck.

My query is

```
 Friend.joins('INNER JOIN users ON friends.friend_id = users.id').where("user_id=? AND (status=? or status=?)", 4,"true","").pluck("users.first_name, users.last_name")
```

It is to join with friends with users and get users first name and last name

Generated SQL command is

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name FROM "friends" INNER JOIN users ON friends.friend_id = users.id WHERE (user_id=4 AND (status='true' or status=''))
```

If i run above command on sqlite browser tool

i am getting response like

```
 first_name  last_name

     user4     y
     user5     y
```

but from command line with pluck

```
   ["y", "y"]
```

and command line with find_by_sql

```
 [#<Friend >, #<Friend >]
```

What's wrong in my code, or is it problem with pluck and find_by_sql

How can i resolve the problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config/initializers/pluck_all.rb

```
module ActiveRecord
class Relation
  def pluck_all(*args)
  args.map! do |column_name|
    if column_name.is_a?(Symbol) && column_names.include?(column_name.to_s)
      "#{connection.quote_table_name(table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(column_name)}"
    else
      column_name.to_s
    end
  end

  relation = clone
  relation.select_values = args
  klass.connection.select_all(relation.arel).map! do |attributes|
    initialized_attributes = klass.initialize_attributes(attributes)
    attributes.each do |key, attribute|
      attributes[key] = klass.type_cast_attribute(key, initialized_attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

end
end

```
 Friend.joins('INNER JOIN users ON friends.friend_id = users.id').where("user_id=? AND (status=? or status=?)", 4,"true","").pluck_all("users.first_name","users.last_name")
```

resolves my issue, it's purely a pluck problem.

thanks for a [great tutorial](http://meltingice.net/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails 4 you can do

Instead of

```
.pluck("users.first_name, users.last_name")
```

Try

```
.pluck("users.first_name", "users.last_name")
```

In rails 3 you'll want to use select to select those specific fields

```
.select("users.first_name", "users.last_name")
```

Comment: It's giving an error  wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?  Sorry, forgot pluck got modified with rails 4.  Rails 3 will only accept 1 argument.

Comment: i am using rails3 only

Answer (score 0):

In terms of making a rails 3 method that behaves the same as the Rails 4 pluck with multiple columns. 
This outputs a similar array (rather than a hashed key value collection).

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Relation
    def pluck_all(*args)
      args.map! do |column_name|
        if column_name.is_a?(Symbol) && column_names.include?(column_name.to_s)
          "#{connection.quote_table_name(table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(column_name)}"
        else
          column_name.to_s
        end
      end

      relation = clone
      relation.select_values = args
      klass.connection.select_all(relation.arel).map! do |attributes|
        initialized_attributes = klass.initialize_attributes(attributes)
        attributes.map do |key, attribute|
          klass.type_cast_attribute(key, initialized_attributes)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Standing on the shoulders of giants and all (@santosh)

Answer (score 0):

The [article](http://meltingice.net/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/) @santosh shared was great until I'm going to upgrade from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.

Here is a gem [pluck_all](https://github.com/khiav223577/pluck_all/network) to solve this, making `pluck_all` method support not only in Rails 3 but in Rails 4 and Rails 5. Hope this will help those who are going to upgrade rails version.